# AlertDialog with images

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-alertdialog

I want to create and dialog, which appears and a person can choose one of eight options.
So i found, that the best will be class 'Alert Dialog'. I know, how to create an object with this class, which displays a list of text options to choose from. But I decided, to now show text option, but images, so I created something like this:

`AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(StartGameActivity.this);`

```
    builder.setTitle(R.string.pickColor);

           builder.setItems(R.array.colorArray, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                      it's not important what is inside this function
                   }
```

}

But when I run my application and the alert dialog appears - i see only text, which i think is the path to the folder where is my image (it's something like: res/drawable-xhpi/image_name.jpeg)

I was looking for a solution to this problem, but, this which I found were useless.
I have read, that I should maybe use an ListAdapter or LayoutInflater, but I not sure how I can use this. Can anybody explain me how make a list of images inside the AletDialog?

Comment: You can use AlertDialog.Builder.setView(View) function to set your own view to dialog. You can inflate a layout of your choice and set it to the dialog.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your array is a list of resource ids...

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(StartGameActivity.this);
builder.setTitle(R.string.pickColor);
ListView lv = new ListView(getActivity());
lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), -1) {
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Resources res = getResources();
        TypedArray colorArray = res.obtainTypedArray(R.array.colorArray);
        Drawable drawable = colorArray.getDrawable(position);
        ImageView v = new ImageView(getActivity());
        v.setImageDrawable(drawable);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        Resources res = getResources();
        TypedArray colorArray = res.obtainTypedArray(R.array.colorArray);
        return colorArray.length();
    }
});
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        // do click stuff
    }

});
builder.setView(lv);
```